# Repintar tela a cada pouco tempo sem travar - C++

Tags: c++, qt, thread

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Tenho que repintar a tela a cada pouco tempo para que objetos na tela se mecham por conta, porém isso tem que ocorrer de maneira que o programa não trave.

Já tentei fazer uma Thread e chamar o método update porém a tela fica branca, toda travada.

Basicamente, eu preciso que isso ocorra a cada tempo especifico, mas que não influencie nos depois processos do programa (como eventos de teclado e mouse).

```
void atualizar(){
   X = X - 20;
   repaint();
}
```

Acredito que o melhor é com Thread, mas não consegui implementar da maneira correta, mesmo seguindo a documentação oficial do QT.

Outro ponto, ao tentar fazer com Thread o evento de pintura acaba sendo chamado duas vezes, ocorrendo em crash no programa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução seria usar um [QTimer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html):

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(repaint()));
timer->setInterval(200); // 200 milissegundos
timer->start(); // Se preferir, pode usar start(200) e remover a linha do setInterval
```

Lembre-se que todas as operações de GUI devem ser feitas na thread principal, e quando precisar usar outras threads, a comunicação deve ser feita por SIGNALS e SLOTS, nunca chamando os métodos diretamente entre threads.

Quando precisar desativar o timer, basta chamar `timer->stop();` e para reativar, basta nova chamada a `timer->start();`

Veja mais detalhes no **[manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtimer.html)** da Qt.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta. Fico muito agradecido por ter resolvido meu problema.